# Can I update pycharm intellisense for python?

Tags: python, intellisense

I want to know if it's possible to update Pycharm intellisense for python which doesn't care about capital or normal letters?
It's a pain in the neck to try both each time.
Currently I'm using pycharm 3.0 and python 2.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my answer [on the JetBrains website](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html):

> File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor - Code Completion
>
> From this drop-down list, select the degree to which you want PyCharm
>   to take into consideration the case sensitivity when suggesting
>   matches for code completion. The available options are:
>
> - All: The lookup list includes only those items that match the case of all typed letters. This option is most restrictive.
> - None: The lookup list includes all matches regardless of their case.
> - First letter: The lookup list includes only the items with the first letter matching.